# Aligning divs inside different sections depending on one div's height

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

[this is the design i'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RugHa.png)

The cards on the right are part of a carousel. Each title(program name, degree,etc) are seperate divs. The problem i'm facing is, I need to align the titles with the data, and if the text in either the title or the data wraps to the next line, I want there to be an empty line below the other entity. For example, for the title 'Program name', if the data wraps to a second line, there must be an empty space under 'Program name' and vice versa.
[this is the mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zucdX.png)

I have tried aligning them manually, but I am unable to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a straight answer to the question, but - in my opinion - there are three different ways of thinking about this problem. (surely needs design approval)

1. You can fix the width of left-side entities (like program name, ...) and leave the right-side content X-axis scrollable.
2. The other way that might help but needs more effort to do, is using a transformed table for small screens.
3. And the last approach is to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. I won't recommend it because you're gonna lose part of the titles on small screens. The only reason it might be helpful is that you have zero percent of the user using that screen size and only wants to make it work.

In this [link](https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/5-practical-solutions-to-make-responsive-data-tables-ff031c48b122) try looking at **Collapsed** title and **Transformed**.

I hope this helps.